# Using newline characters in the HttpStatusCodeResult of ASP.NET MVC Action method is returning empty message when ajax is used to the action method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am executing a ajax call from the cshtml page of an ASPNET MVC application, which calls an action method `Delete` from `HomeController`.
The action method catches exception message, if any occurred during the delete operation. The exception message contains `'\r\n'` characters. I am unable to read the error message in ajax method. Without the `'\r\n\'` characters, the message is read.

**ASPNET MVC Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(string input)
{
    try
    {
        //Code to call service to delete
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
         int errorCode;
         errorCode = int.TryParse(ex.ErrorCode, out errorCode) ? errorCode : (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

         var errorMessage = ex.Message ?? "An error occured";
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(errorCode, errorMessage);
    }

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

**Ajax call**

```
var input = @Viewbag.Input;
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")',
       data: {
          "input": input
       },
       success: function () {
          alert('Deleted Successfully');
       },
       error: function (xmlHttp) {
          var title = xmlHttp.responseText.substring(xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("<title>") + 7, xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("</title>"));
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          alert(div.textContent);
       }
  });
```

The above code is not returning any text data in `xmlHttp` of the ajax error method. The `ex.Message` contains `'\r\n'`.

Updating the action method code to sanitize the exception message as below helps in reading the message.

`var errorMessage = ex.Message is null ? "An error occured" : ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");`

But I could not see the `alert` in ajax call in multiple lines.
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

In your action `Task<IActionResult> Delete(string input)`, you are returning a          `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(errorCode, errorMessage);` which I am not quite familiar with and I haven't worked with that function. I almost always have prefered to create my own public class for handling responses from `HttpPost` requests.

```
public class BaseResponse
{
   public string status { get; set; }
   public string message { get; set; }
   public string statusCode { get; set; }     
 }


 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Delete(string input)
 {

   BaseResponse resp = new BaseResponse();
   try {
        // Code to call service to delete

        var resultContent = deleteService(input); // your service here, you might have to await this function depending on how you set it up.
        var jsonResponse = resultContent.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseResponse>(jsonResponse.Result);
            resp.status = "OK";
            resp.message = "Success message.";
            resp.statusCode = result.StatusCode.toString();
        }
        else
        {
            resp = new BaseResponse();
            resp.status = "KO";
            resp.message = "error message";
            resp.statusCode = result.StatusCode.toString();
        }
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       resp = new BaseResponse();
       int errorCode;
       errorCode = int.TryParse(ex.ErrorCode, out errorCode) ? errorCode : (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        var errorMessage = ex.Message is null ? "An error occured" : ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
        resp.status = "KO";
        resp.message = errorMessage; 
        resp.statusCode = errorCode.toString();
    }
  
   return resp;
}
```

In my frank opinion, it is better to handle your response message inside your c# `HttpPost` function instead of doing all of this inside your AJAX request

```
var title = xmlHttp.responseText.substring(xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf(" 
              <title>") + 7, xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("</title>"));
```

In terms of programming logic, it is wiser to separate this kind of procedure in your Controller rather than putting it inside your front-end side.

```
var input = @Viewbag.Input;
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Home")',
       data: {
          "input": input
       },
       success: function (response) {
           if(response.status === "OK") {
              alert('Deleted Successfully');
           } else {
                alert('Not deleted' + response.statusCode);
           }
       },
       error: function (response) {
          if(response.status === "KO") {     
                  // var title = xmlHttp.responseText.substring(xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf(" 
          //<title>") + 7, xmlHttp.responseText.indexOf("</title>")); 
             // you can handle your message here.
               var title = response.message;
               var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = title;
           }

       }
  });
```